# How to remove duplicate elements from a nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a list as

```
list = Table[{{i, j}, {k, l}}, {i, 1, 2, 1}, {j, 1, 2, 1}, {k, 1, 2, 
              1}, {l, 1, 2, 1}];
```

The outcome of this is:

```
{{{{{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}}, {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 
  1}, {2, 2}}}}, {{{{1, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}}, {{{1, 
  2}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}}}}, {{{{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 
  1}, {1, 2}}}, {{{2, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}}}, {{{{2, 
  2}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {1, 2}}}, {{{2, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 
  2}}}}}}
```

I consider, `{{a, b}, {c, d}}}` and `{{c, d}, {a, b}}}` as duplicate and I want to remove the duplicates from the list.

I further wish to remove elements of the form `{{a, b}, {a, b}}}` (This is answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164414/how-to-delete-certain-elements-from-a-list/164424#164424). However, I don't know how to accomplish the first task and do both the operations together using `Pick` or `DeleteCases`).

It would be more appreciable if some conditioning can be imposed while constructing the list itself to accomplish the above-mentioned tasks.

Comment: I do not get what your question is. Your lis has `Dimensions` `{2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}`, it seems to me that you are talking about a 2x2xn list, if that is right can you flatten it down in the right way for us first?

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 The list is designed in this form for a specific purpose to be used later on. So it should not be flattened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The list ... **should not be flattened**.*

```
ClearAll[orderlessDeDupe]
orderlessDeDupe = Module[{g}, 
 g[{r_, r_}] := Sequence[]; 
 g[{r_, s_}] := (g[{r, s}] = g[{s, r}] = Sequence[]; {r, s});
 Map[g, #, {-3}]]&;

orderlessDeDupe @ list
```

> {{{{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}}, {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}},
>       {{}, {{{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}}}},
>       {{{}, {{{2, 1}, {2, 2}}}}, {{}, {}}}}

If you want to delete the empty sets, use `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
% //. {} -> Sequence[]
```

> {{{{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}},
>         {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}},
>         {{{{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}}}},
>         {{{{{2, 1}, {2, 2}}}}}}

**Note:** If it weren't for the requirement to keep the structure intact, we could have simply done

```
Subsets[Tuples[{1, 2}, {2}], {2}]
```

> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}}

**Update:** An alternative method deleting the positions of unwanted pairs:

```
ClearAll[orderlessDeDupe2]
orderlessDeDupe2[list_] := Module[{level3pos = Position[list, _, {-3}],
  pos = Position[list, Alternatives @@ Subsets[Tuples[{1, 2}, {2}], {2}]]}, 
  Delete[list, Complement[level3pos, pos]]]

orderlessDeDupe2[list] == orderlessDeDupe[list]
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
Cases[Union[Tuples[{1, 2}, {2, 2}], SameTest -> ((Reverse[#1] == #2) &)], 
      {a_, b_} /; a != b
     ]

(* {
    {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, 
    {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}
   } 
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses built-in functions only:

```
list = 
  Table[{{i, j}, {k, l}}, {i, 1, 2, 1}, {j, 1, 2, 1}, {k, 1, 2, 
    1}, {l, 1, 2, 1}];

pos = 
  Map[Position[list, # | Reverse[#], Infinity] &, Flatten[list, 3]];
Length /@ pos
(* {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1} *)

list2 = 
  Fold[If[Length[#2] == 1, #1, 
     ReplacePart[#1, Rest[#2] -> Nothing]] &, list, pos];

res = DeleteCases[list2, {{a_, b_}, {a_, b_}}, Infinity] //. {} -> Nothing

(* {{{{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}}, {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 
  2}}}}, {{{{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}}}}, {{{{{2, 1}, {2, 
  2}}}}}} *)
```